# sdb Appears in launcher?

Tags: usb

Whenever I insert a USB drive into my computer the icon for usb appears, however it also adds an icon for /dev/sdb as well;  I can't figure out why.  Any thoughts on how to remove this?

Comment: Does this happen for any USB drive, or just a specific drive?

Comment: How is the USB drive partitioned?

Comment: It seems to happen to any USB I insert

Comment: could you add a screenshot of the extra icon?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by backtracking.

I have a USB drive that was faulty and when inserted it was detected by the program "DISKS".  I turned off auto-mount options in that program and tried to mount it manually.

That didn't work, so when I unplugged the USB it must have kept those settings for the others.  I worked backwards and viewed the settings for that USB and changed them to auto-mount and removed the device.  Now SDB doesn't appear in the launcher for any USB.